# Rails 5 Array of Objects from Cocoon Gem Nested Attributes Printing to View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a weird situation going on I can't figure out.  I have a `pages` model and a `videos` model.  The videos model is simple a nested model in pages.  Everything works, but for some reason when I am looping through the videos nested attributes, it prints the array of objects to the view.  I've included my loop and screenshot below.

**pages/show.html.erb**

```
...
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <%= @page.videos.each do |v| %>
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<%= v.youtube %>" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

[image]

Comment: what happens if you do `src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/#{v.youtube}"` for your interpolation? or `https://www.youtube.com/embed/#{v.youtube[0]}"`

Comment: None of those add the object.  I should also say that if I remove the entire `<iframe>` section all together and just have an empty loop; the array still prints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove '=' in the loop this is making array to print 
Correct code snippet will be like this

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <% @page.videos.each do |v| %>
         <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<%= v.youtube %>" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <% end %>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that.  Thanks.